# LLamar un metodo C# desde JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Buen día presento un inconveniente, necesito llamar un método c# desde JavaScript, este requiere de una url, cuando depuro mi aplicación en .net este no me muestra el .aspx en la url, por esto la función de js ya no encuentra el método en el formulario, como podría llamar al formulario aspx sin necesidad de colocarlo en la función js.

```js
function Llena_Modal_Detalles(p_id_tabla) {
    if (p_id_tabla !== '') {
        //compara datos C# y JS
        var data = { p_id_tabla: p_id_tabla }
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        idTip = parseInt(p_id_tabla);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; utf-8',
            //identifica el Form y el metodo a utilizar de C#
            **url: 'Frm_ModuloSeguimiento.aspx/Llenar_datos_modal',**
            data: data,
```

este el método que la función de js llama en el formulario aspx

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] Llenar_datos_modal(int p_id_tabla)
    {
```

Comment: Hola Samuel,  compartenos el código que llevas hecho por favor, así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Samuel. Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Saludos. Pon tu código para poder indicarte (en lo posible) donde puede ser el detalle que te falta o la forma en que debe estar para que funcione.

Comment: ya actualize gracias por el apoyo

Comment: El nombre del método me da idea que estás confundido acerca de qué está accesible desde el servidor y qué desde el cliente. Ya que en el servidor no vas a tener acceso al _modal_ o a sus elementos, que viven en el cliente. Quizás sea mejor que muestres algo de código para confirmar la sospecha o evitar esa confusión.

Comment: Empezemos por acomodarte las ideas... no llamas a un metodo en aspx... llamas a una api que tiene como endpoint lo que vos queres llamar... de esa forma, vas a poder buscar mejor lo que necesitas...

Comment: No me queda del todo claro que buscas realizar dentro del código, acá tengo 2 opciones de lo que puede estar corriendo, la primera estás tratando de manipular un elemento del lado del cliente desde el servidor, esto no te va a funcionar. La segunda opción el método que estás intentando llamar se encuentra dentro de un formulario y para el ajax que estás desarrollando es imposible encontrar esa ruta, te recomiendo crear un servicio de asmx donde tengas tus endpoints requeridos y cambiar la ruta en la que apuntas en el ajax